# PCI scanner showing TLSv1 support for port 2078 and 2080

Tags: cpanel, whm, pci-compliance

I have a VPS with WHM and cPanel installed. I run the trustwave PCI scanner and is showing me errors:

1. TLSv1.0 Supported - tcp/2078
   Evidence:
   Cipher Suite: TLSv1 : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA Cipher Suite: TLSv1 : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA Cipher Suite: TLSv1 : AES256-SHA
   Cipher Suite: TLSv1 : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA Cipher Suite: TLSv1 : DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA Cipher Suite: TLSv1 : AES128-SHA
2. TLSv1.0 Supported - tcp/2080
   Evidence:
   Cipher Suite: TLSv1 : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA Cipher Suite: TLSv1 : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA Cipher Suite: TLSv1 : AES256-SHA
   Cipher Suite: TLSv1 : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA Cipher Suite: TLSv1 : DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA Cipher Suite: TLSv1 : AES128-SHA

I had more problems with TLSv1.0 on different ports, but I managed to fix them. I can't find any help online with these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it myself by blocking incoming traffic to these ports:

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 2080 -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 2078 -j DROP
```